# Notify via email if something wrong got happened in the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
fileexist=0
  mv /data/Finished-HADOOP_EXPORT_&Date#.done /data/clv/daily/archieve-wip/
  fileexist=1
--some other script below
```

Above is the shell script I have in which in the for loop, I am moving some files. I want to notify myself via email if something wrong got happened in the moving process, as I am running this script on the Hadoop Cluster, so it might be possible that cluster went down while this was running etc etc. So how can I have better `error handling mechanism` in this shell script? Any thoughts?

Comment: Redirect errors to a file, then if the file has contents, mail it to you? You might consider mailing a file anyway, else you'll think all is OK when you got no mail, when in fact the entire server crashed and couldn't mail.

Comment: Don't try to iterate over the output of `ls`. Switch to the directory, and iterate over a pattern: `cd /data/....; for i in *; do ...; done`

Comment: This has nothing to do with hadoop, you may want to remove the tag.

Comment: @chepner, Is there any benefit in doing so if I switch over the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Well, atleast you need to know "What are you expecting to go wrong". based on that you can do this

```
 mv ..... 2> err.log
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
   cat ./err.log | mailx -s "Error report" admin@abc.com
   rm ./err.log
 fi
```

Or as [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) suggested, use-

```
trap 'rm -f err.log' 0; mv ... 2> err.log || < err.log mailx ...
```

`mv` may return a non-zero return code upon error, and `$?` returns that error code. If the entire server goes down then unfortunately this script doesn't run either so that's better left to more advanced monitoring tools such as [Foglight](http://www.quest.com/foglight/) running on a different monitoring server. For more basic checks, you can use method above.

Comment: Instead of redirecting each `mv` individually, you can also redirect `stderr` of the whole script with `exec 2>/some/file`.  The check to see if that file is of non-zero size and send an email if it is.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in many ways, its more of choice and requirement. I have developed almost a dozen scripts that work the way you mentioned.

Comment: This would be better written: `trap 'rm -f err.log' 0; mv ... 2> err.log || < err.log mailx ...`